# How to check if array contains defined values using supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, supertest, should.js

Let's say in response during tests I have such array:

```js
array = [
 'a',   'b',
 'c',   'd',
 'e',   'f',
 'g',   'h',
 'i',   'j'
]
```

And I want to check if this array really contains those values:

```js
array.should.be.a.Array()
.with.lengthOf(response.body.length)
.and.have.properties('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j');
```

As you can see I can't use here `have.properties` because it's array, not object. So, how can I check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`should.deepEqual`](https://shouldjs.github.io/#should-deepequal) to match length and values with order

```js
const arr = [
 'a',   'b',
 'c',   'd',
 'e',   'f',
 'g',   'h',
 'i',   'j'
];

arr.should.deepEqual(arr);
console.log("test passed");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/should.js/13.2.3/should.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an exact match go with Chandan's answer, if you need to match a subset, you can use `should.containDeep` (see the [docs](https://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-containdeep)). Here's an example:

```js
const arr = [
 'a',   'b',
 'c',   'd',
 'e',   'f',
 'g',   'h',
 'i',   'j'
];

arr.should.containDeep(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
console.log("test passed");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/should.js/13.2.3/should.min.js"></script>
```